# Javascript type conversion between string and number resulting in inconsistent results

Tags: javascript

I'm working on integrating an Instagram login, authentication and search on a platform, and came across this peculiar problem.

For only this ID that I could find, going both from Integer to String, and the other way around, causes the resulting number to be greater by 1 than the original input. Using the .toString() method from Number to go from Number to String, as well as parseInt() and Number() functions to go from String to Number caused this issue. The specific number is 17841400373590127.

On many different IDs, both of greater and smaller numerical values, I didn't encounter this issue. With this value changing, it causes problems down the line when searching by this ID in our databases and not finding any result.

The ideal solution would be our backend API delivering the same type in all cases, but it would be nice to have the possibility of casting in our Vue frontend without issues like these occurring. Does anyone have an idea why this occurs, and how to possibly avoid it?

On the print screen I demonstrate the problem occurring in chrome's console.

[bug demonstration chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAvyT.png)

Comment: Your number `17841400373590127` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` so you'll get unexpected behavior if you try and use it as a number - either use a [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (of some sort), or keep it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you're getting a inaccurate parsing result because the number in question is greater than JS `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, that is, the greatest number which can be represented and handled with accuracy. If you try to use greater numbers, you'll be subject to getting mathematically incorrect results.

JS also has `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` and limits for decimal digits.

If you need to convert an unsafe integer from `Number` to `String`, you can use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
// Here, I'm creating a BigInt by appending "n" to the number.

console.log((17841400373590127n).toString());
```

Unfotunately, it's impossible to convert such number from `String` or `BigInt` to `Number` and get a correct result.